# tabBarItem image shrinking on setBadgeValue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbaritem

I have created a `tabBarItem` with an image. I have set `badgeValue` for it, which displays count of  messages. When `badgeValue` is displayed, that tabBarItem image shrinks suddenly. Here is a screenshot of the situation:

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7o7et.png)

And here is the code I used:

```
[tabbaritem4 setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Btn_Taskbar_Chat-Over.fw.png"] withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Btn_Taskbar_Chat.fw.png"]];
tabbaritem4.imageInsets=UIEdgeInsetsMake(25,12,10,13);

-(void)getAllUnReadMessages:(NSInteger)countMessage
{
    if(countMessage >= 1)
    {
        [tabbaritem4 setBadgeValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",countMessage]];
    }
    else
    {
        [tabbaritem4 setBadgeValue:nil];
    }
}
```

Comment: post your code what you have tried?

Comment: @Sunny is there problem with my code?

Comment: iam asking about type of the objecte?

Comment: @Sunny did i give correct answer to your question?